# How to prevent the Blue Golem resetting?

Tags: league-of-legends

Everyone who played jungler should know the situation:
Mid can't pull for whichever reason - for example on account of being Fizz - so someone else attacks once and runs away, you as jungler start punching the golem and then it resets while all your cooldowns are down and you end up taking twice the damage you should have taken.

What can the one pulling or the jungler do to prevent that situation?
Does it happen because the Jungler attacks too late or is it the pulling person running away too fast/slow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9qzM.jpg) that I just saw on League of Legends Reddit has a good way of explaining why and when it resets.

[image]

> When someone attacks (leashes) blue buff, it will attempt to move towards that player to attack. However, blue buff can not move outside of its indicated aggro range. If the player that attacked blue first is still within its aggro range, it will continue to try and reach that player. When it can not, and it reaches its aggro range border, it will soft reset up to a maximum of 2 times. If the player that attacked it first leaves aggro range, it will continue to try, and move towards that player until it reaches its aggro range again. When it does, it will attempt to attack a player that is within the aggro range (and has attacked blue). Hard resets happen when it soft resets 2 times, then resets again. It will return to its original spawning location, ignoring all actions made by players.

Answer (score 4):

As jungler, there is not much you can do. The guy who pulls has to get away immediatly. If the puller only hits the blue buff ONCE and just runs away, you will be fine in 99% of the cases. If he tries to apply dmg to the blue buff (2-3 is already enough) the blue buff might reaggro him, go out of his "camp zone" and reset cuase of that.

So just tell whoever has to pull to just pull and "gtfo".

Comment: I'm quite sure i've seen a golem resetting after getting shot just once from an AD carry. Does the aggro depend on damage (i.e. if he uses a skill, it takes longer to get aggro as jungler) or do you just need to break line of sight?

Comment: Blue buff has a certain "range" where he aggros. If the AD carry pulls blue buff and you are stnading in the bush hitting the Golem, you can be unlucky and hit him just as he resets (which wont count). So you are hiding in the bush, invisible for the golem, the ad carry just ran out of sight of the golem, so he has no enemy to attack and resets. Either dont step into a bsuh or tell your AD to run away as soon as he pulls, cause if he doesnt stop before leaving the line of sight of Blue Buff, there is NO way he can reset.